# How to record voice for a slide in LibreOffice Impress?

Tags: libreoffice, extension, audio-recording

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS. I want to record my voice for a slide in LibreOffice Impress. I searched but I didn't get it. Please, anyone, help me!

Answer (score 7):

You'll need an audio recording software first.

[Ubuntu Help Page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AudioCapture) recommends Audacity.

1. Install [Audacity.](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/audacity)
2. Go to menu: **Edit ▸ Preferences ▸ Devices**. Go to section **Recording**
3. Choose the appropriate recording device (make sure the device is plugged-in) and click OK.
4. Record the audio.

After you've recorded your voice, go to Impress top menu and **Insert-> Movie and Sound.** Find your sound file and click **Open** to add it in your slide.

Comment: I installed Audacity but I am unable to see Devices in Preferences...

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? Do you have a microphone plugged in?

Comment: Fine it's working..

Answer (score 0):

There is also an [OpenOffice extension eVoice](https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/project/evoice). It seems that it needs Java Runtime Environment (JRE). Although it is old, it works with my current LibreOffice 7.1.
The only annoying thing in my setting is that the eVoice window is placed in the middle of the LibreOffice window and the slide is not well visible. As workaround I enlarged the slide pane and could read the text there.